# Select Box onchange Update Multiple Items

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying get a select box to use the onchange function to update multiple items surrounding it. Here is my code so far:

```
function picture() {
var imglink;
var imgprice;
var picture_type = document.getElementById('picture_type').value;
if ("picture_type" == "1") {
    imglink = "img1.png";
    imgprice = "$xx.xx";
}
if("picture_type" == "2") {
    imglink = "img2.png";
    imgprice = "$xxx.xx";
}
else {
    document.getElementById('iphoneprice').style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('phoneimg').src = imglink;
document.getElementById('iphoneprice').innerHTML = imgprice;
}
```

And the matching HTML:

```
<select id="picture_type" onchange="picture()">
<option value="1">iPhone 4</option>
<option value="2">iPhone 4S</option>
</select>
<p id="iphoneprice"></p>
<img id="iphoneimg" src="" />
```

How could I make it successfully update these two variables simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo (`getElementById('phoneimg')` should be `getElementById('iphoneimg')`) and quotes around variable names. This should work:

```
function picture() {
    var imglink;
    var imgprice;
    var picture_type = document.getElementById('picture_type').value;
    if (picture_type == "1") {
        imglink = "img1.png";
        imgprice = "$xx.xx";
    }
    else if(picture_type == "2") {
        imglink = "img2.png";
        imgprice = "$xxx.xx";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('iphoneprice').style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('iphoneimg').src = imglink;
    document.getElementById('iphoneprice').innerHTML = imgprice;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7souy65z/)**